# Mapbox via a proxy

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl-js

Our React web app uses Mapbox for maps and geocoding.

For some customers, the end user browser has no internet connectivity. We would like to forward Mapbox requests in such case through a proxy which we will set up.
Does Mapbox supports such a use case?
Is it just about changing Mapbox api domain? Or is there something else that should be done.

We noticed that Mapbox is sending other metrics related requests from within the library, and we will need to handle that case as well.